# Pair notation in multivariate polynomial rings: ideal vs. tuple

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is this notation in multivariable polynomial rings?

Consider the map $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^2 \to (x,y)$ where $(x,y)$ is the ideal generated by $x,y$ given by $(f,g) \mapsto fx+gy$. I take it to mean $(f(x,y),g(x,y)) \mapsto xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)$ I could certainly be wrong. Any suggestions?

But then I see the user defining a map $\Bbb C[x,y]\to \Bbb C[x,y]^2$ given by $f\to (−yf,xf),$ so I was confused. Which I take to mean $f(x,y)\to (−yf(x,y),xf(x,y))$. I don't understand why he defines elements on different sides.

Why does he not define the map consistently?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: @Randall but then I see the user defining a map $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]^2$  given by $f \mapsto (-yf,xf)$, so I was confused. Which I take to mean $f(x,y) \mapsto (-yf(x,y),xf(x,y)$ I don't understand why he defines elements on different sides.

Comment: That is also a map, with different domain and codomain.

Comment: @Randall why does he not define the map consistently?

Comment: It's a different map.  Where is the inconsistency?  On one hand $(x,y)$ means an ideal, on the other $(-yf,xf)$ is an ordered pair/element of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what the map means. The second map you mention
\begin{align*}
\alpha : \Bbb{C}[x,y]&\to\Bbb{C}[x,y]^2\\
f&\mapsto (-yf,xf)
\end{align*}
is a completely different map. It is related to your first map $\beta : \Bbb{C}[x,y]^2\to(x,y)$ by the following formula: $\beta\circ\alpha = 0.$ We can check this explicitly:
\begin{align*}
\beta\circ\alpha(f) &= \beta(-yf(x,y),xf(x,y))\\
&= x(-yf(x,y)) + y(xf(x,y))\\
&= -xy f(x,y) + xy f(x,y) = 0.
\end{align*}
In fact, the sequence
$$
0\to\Bbb{C}[x,y]\xrightarrow{\alpha}\Bbb{C}[x,y]^2\xrightarrow{\beta}(x,y)\to 0
$$
is a short exact sequence, meaning that the kernel of $\beta$ is precisely the image of $\alpha$ (and that $\alpha$ is injective and $\beta$ is surjective). To check this, you need to show that if $(f,g)\in\ker(\beta),$ then $(f,g) = (-yh, xh)$ for some $h\in\Bbb{C}[x,y].$ First, note that $(f,g)\in\ker(\beta)$ implies that $xf(x,y) = -yg(x,y).$

Since $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ is a unique factorization domain and $x$ and $y$ are prime elements, it follows that $x\mid g$ and $y\mid f$. So, we may write $f(x,y) = y \tilde{f}(x,y)$ and $g(x,y) = x\tilde{g}(x,y)$ for some polynomials $\tilde{f},\tilde{g}\in\Bbb{C}[x,y].$

But now we have $xy\tilde{f}(x,y) = -xy\tilde{g}(x,y),$ and since $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ is a domain, it follows that $\tilde{f}(x,y) = -\tilde{g}(x,y).$ Hence, we have shown that $\ker(\beta) = \operatorname{im}(\alpha).$

What the author has done is construct a free resolution of $(x,y)$ as a $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$-module.

---

TL;DR: Your first map has domain $\Bbb{C}[x,y]^2$ and codomain $(x,y),$  where the former is ordered pairs of polynomials in two variables $x$ and $y$ and coefficients in the complex numbers, and the latter is the ideal of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ generated by $x$ and $y.$ Remember, $(x,y)$ is simply shorthand for the following set:
$$
\{f(x,y)\in\Bbb{C}[x,y]\mid f(x,y) = x p(x,y) + y q(x,y)\textrm{ for some }p(x,y),q(x,y)\in\Bbb{C}[x,y]\}.
$$
So the first map takes an ordered pair $(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ (not an ideal!) and sends it to the element $xf(x,y) + yg(x,y),$ which is in the ideal $(x,y).$

Your second map has domain $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ and codomain $\Bbb{C}[x,y]^2,$ and sends a polynomial $f(x,y)$ to the ordered pair of polynomials $(-y f(x,y), xf(x,y)),$ which is an element of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]^2$ (not an ideal!).